# In Python, how to cancel an ongoing copy process?

Tags: python-2.7, interrupt, shutil

I have a copy function that uses `copyfile` from [shutil](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfile). This runs within a RESTful API. Whenever copying a very large file, I would like to implement a way to interrupt the specific call without having to `exit` the service.

```
def copy_file(source, destination):
    '''
    API Endpoint for copy_file
    '''
    from shutil import copyfile

    if not os.path.exists(os.path.dirname(destination)):
        os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(destination))

    copyfile(source, destination)    
    return True
```

My attempt at the moment is to run this process on a different thread which I could then have more granular control (`thread.exit()`), but I was wondering if there was a simpler idea.